# Which is better for timing, nanoTime or elapsedRealtimeNanos?

Tags: android, timer, nanotime

Both seem to be appropriate for timing things on Android. How are they different? Which one is best for timing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's not really much of a difference, but they use different Linux clocks under the hood.

[`nanoTime()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) uses either `clock_gettime()` or `gettimeofday()`: see the [code here (part of Dalvik VM)](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/dalvik/vm/Misc.cpp#446).

[`elapsedRealtimeNanos()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock#elapsedRealtimeNanos()) used to use `clock_gettime()`, but it no longer does. Instead, it now issues an `ioctl` to the `/dev/alarm` device ([see code here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/native/libs/utils/SystemClock.cpp#152)), but I'm not exactly sure what the `alarm` device driver uses.

I've used `elapsedRealtimeNanos()` for a long time with no trouble, but not for any specific reason. Just make sure you realize that neither of these functions will provide the wall clock time.